# Random mutation

Tags: python

I am a beginner python coder and I am writing a code to generate random mutation at random position.
I have written a function which includes:

1. The sequence where mutation happens
2. A List of nucleotide from which a nucleotide is selected randomly and replaced to the nucleotide of the original sequence.

Basic concept of the code:

Say we have to pick one ball from (A) basket and replace with another ball from another basket (B). The colors of the two balls need to be different.

I know I need to use while loop but I am not able to do it.

```
def random(s)

    length = len(s)
    seq = list(s)
    nucl = "ATGC" ## pick one nucleotide from this list
    lengthnucl= len(nucleotide_list)

    position_orgseq = np.random.choice(range(0,length))
    position_nucl = np.random.choice(range(0,lengthnucl))
    #while c < length:

    ##if the two nucleotides chosen are not equaul then:
    #two nucleotides are from
    # TTTTGGGCCCCAAA - original seq, ATGC = nucloetide list
    if seq[position_orgseq] != nucleotide_list[position_nucl]:


        seq[position_orgseq] = nucleotide_list[position_nucl]
        final = "".join(seq)
    return s,final


actual_seq, mut_seq = random("TTTTGGGCCCCAAA")
print(actual_seq)
print(mut_seq)
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy random choice?  Seems like massive overhead for something you can just use with `import random` and where did `nucleotide_list` come from?

Answer (score 0):

First, as @Error - Syntatical Remorse pointed out in the comment, there is no need to import numpy, use built in random instead (specifically, you can use random.randint()).

Your code as is, doesn't run, you have misnamed variables. Other than that, you are close. Your hunch to using a while loop is correct. You can simply keep looping until your two random values don't give the same nucleotide in the two lists. Like so:

```
from random import randint


def random(s):
    length = len(s)
    seq = list(s)

    nucl = "ATGC"
    lengthnucl = len(nucl)

    position_orgseq = randint(0, length - 1)
    position_nucl = randint(0, lengthnucl - 1)
    while seq[position_orgseq] == nucl[position_nucl]:
        position_orgseq = randint(0, length - 1)
        position_nucl = randint(0, lengthnucl - 1)

    seq[position_orgseq] = nucl[position_nucl]
    final = "".join(seq)

    return s, final


actual_seq, mut_seq = random("TTTTGGGCCCCAAA")
print(actual_seq)
print(mut_seq)
```

This may be optimized further.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems I overwhelmed myself for this. But thank you for your effort!